# How to convert UTC Date by Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, sharepoint-2010, format, momentjs

I get date from Web Service have format date like `"2013-02-06T10:40:56.027"` how to convert it to `"2/6/2013 2:40 AM"`.

[image]

Web Service I get from SocialDataService of Sharepoint 2010

I try [moment](http://momentjs.com/) javascript:

```
var date = moment(lastModifiedTime);

var result = date.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A");
```

but result not correct hour: `02/06/2013 10:40 AM`

I expected result: `02/06/2013 2:40 AM`

Comment: The original time does not have timezone information. Seems you have to calculate your local time with your timezone (or user's timezone) ?

Comment: do you have formula to calculate for US timezone?

Comment: i think @ShivanRaptor is saying the service output should contain the timezone info, otherwise it is impossible to know the absolute time.

Comment: @GraceShao Yes, The result of Web Service don't contain the timezone info.

Comment: Nobody can have solution for that?
It really impossible?

Comment: @GaruJwon See the web-service documentation. For instance, it might "really" be returning a UTC date. See if converting `"2013-02-06T10:40:56.027Z"` (note the Z at the end) results in "the desired time". (The desired result looks to be in PST or UTC-8 which is likely "local".)

Comment: @pst you see my image attached, that all information I received from the web service, i look that field on sql server it is datetime field with default value is (getutcdate())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you can assume your service returns UTC time, you could try something like:

```
moment.utc(result_from_service).local()
```

for more details: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/utc/

Answer (score 0):

```
//Manually add time zone to the date string
var date = moment(lastModifiedTime + "+15:00");
var result = date.format("MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm A");
```

Comment: This would be a stronger answer if you explain it in addition to providing code.